# SwiftUI: How to load image in cell view in LazyVGrid without blocking main?

Tags: ios, swiftui, uiimage, task, scrollview

I have coded a simple grid to test proper way of downloading an image and loading it in the cell without degrading performance in SwiftUI.

I am not able to do it so the scrolling stays responsive. My goal is to be able to have a responsive scrolling experience as images are loaded in each cell.

Can somebody help me understand how I can make this code work so that scrolling is not affected by loading images?

```
struct DView: View {
    
    var columnGridItems = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible())
    ]
    
    @State var stuff = [Int]()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            GeometryReader { geo in
                
                let w = geo.size.width / 4
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: columnGridItems, alignment: .center, spacing: 2) {
                        
                        ForEach(stuff, id:\.self) { s in
                            TestView1(i: s)
                                .frame(width:w, height:w)
                                .clipped()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .background(.red)
                .onAppear {
                    for i in 0..<100 {
                        stuff.append(i)
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        
    }
    
}


let localImageUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "f1", withExtension: "jpg")!
let localImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: localImageUrl.path)!
let f1Image = "https://images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_original/t7kg7iu6e2sv8h0vjcip.jpg"
let tileImageURL = URL(string: f1Image)!

struct TestView1:View {
    
    @State var i:Int
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            Color.black
            
            AsyncImage(url: tileImageURL, scale:2)
//            AsyncImage(url: localImageUrl)
//            Image(uiImage: localImage)
            
            Text("Some Text")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Here you can see how the scrolling gets stuck during load:
[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in "low level" and not use a framework for downloading images asynchronously, like Apple's `AsyncImage`? Have in mind that it works from iOS 15+.

Comment: I should try hat. I was not aware of AsyncImage. Seems like the right tool for the job. I'll test it out.

Comment: I've tried to use AsyncImage and edited the question to provide better focus on loading jitter. I am not sure how to fix this. In UIKit this is quite easy to do. Not sure how to do this in SwiftUI and keep scrollview nice and smooth.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm running it by using NukeUI, but still have this laggy performance. Do I need to bridge UIKit?

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, it happens because the images are not cached and so, whenever you scroll and an `AsyncImage` goes out of frame it gets reset.

I think if you try an image handler framework that supports caching, it should get nice and smooth! Can you try using [SDWebImageSwiftUI](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImageSwiftUI) instead of `AsyncImage`?

Comment: I did try the caching route. If you look at the code you'll see a commented out line `AsyncImage(url: localImageUrl)`. That gets the image from disk. I also tried `Image(uiImage: localImage)` which uses the in memory image. It is true I am using a larger image than I would in production, but, I can do that in UIKit (to some extent) and scrolling stays very responsive still.

Comment: I just added the code you’ve provided to a new project and it scrolls just fine! Is there any more code that interacts with that view?

Comment: If I run the code on the latest iPad Pro 5th gen it's acceptable, although you can see a slight jitter. Running it on ` iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation)` it jitters. No, I started a brand new project and that is all it has in it.

Comment: I can run a UICollectionView UIKit app with super heavy cells in it in a large app on a model that's older than the 3rd gen and it runs like butter. SwiftUI on same device is a brick.

Comment: Have you found a fix for this or figured out what was causing it?

Comment: not really, meaning, SwiftUI performance does not compare with UIKit's performance. UIKit scrolling is very solid and smooth even when I load (on purpose) very heavy images. The best thing I found so far is to use NSCache with a custom wrapper around Image. It work pretty good, but, not even close to UIKit's performance. Still using UICollectionView also, since LazyVGrid also has terrible performance.